# How to be better at avoiding failing tests for open source pull request?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, eslint, pull-request

I'm new to open source and contributing, my pull requests rarely pass because the different testing softwares make it difficult to understand what is expected stylewise. One of the main ones is Continuous-integration/travis-c it always gives me that big red X when i submit a pull request. :[
A project I'm doing now has two types lint and jest; the jest tests pass but the lint test is one nightmare. below is an example of one file, I have 2 other files that failed lint's test and below is the most mild of the three.

Is there a way to resolve this without having to go in and fix every indent? also is lint standardized or does the person who set up lint have control over how they want the style to be? Does anyone have a few pointers on learning what is expected in ones code when joining a new project on GitHub?

```
    3:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
   4:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
   5:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
   6:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
   7:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  17:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  18:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  19:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  21:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  22:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  23:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  25:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  26:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  27:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  29:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  30:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  31:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  33:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  34:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  35:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  36:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  37:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  38:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  39:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  41:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  42:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  43:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  44:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  45:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  46:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  47:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  49:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  50:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  51:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  52:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  53:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  54:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  55:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  57:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
  58:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  59:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  60:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  61:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12  indent
  62:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8   indent
  63:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using VSstudio code

Comment: If you go into the settings, set it for spaces instead of tabs, and choose 2 spaces per tab, you should be able to hit Shift+Alt+F, and it will format the file for you.  I know it doesn't seem like a big deal, but it's very useful to enforce style standards in projects (otherwise everyone's files will be different and harder to navigate, not to mention that it looks messy).

Comment: There is a good eslint plugin for VS Code as well, which will underline the places where the rules are being violated.  You can change which rules are enforced, but in general, most of them are there for a reason.  The project you are contributing to should have a style guide somewhere, unless they use the eslint customizations for that.

Comment: Not a problem.  Good luck with your contributions! I think you might as well delete this because it's likely too general to be helpful to someone in the future.